# Roslyn Diagnostic Analyzer RegisterSymbolAction not being called

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

I created a C# diagnostic project for VB, and am having trouble with it.

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSymbolAction(CheckExpression, 
            SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
    }
```

But the breakpoint on the first line of my CheckExpression method never gets hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems.  The first problem was that nuget manager didn’t want to install the Visual Basic portion of the code analysis packages into the c# project, the second was at least partially caused by the first — the syntaxkind namespace is split between VisualBasic and CSharp, and all of course I was referencing the C# namespace.  Once I managed to get the nuget packages installed (did this from the command line instead of the UI), I was able to reference the right namespaces for the vb syntax nodes and the anaylyzer portion is now working.

Hope this helps someone.